# Add Expires Headers on Umbraco website

Tags: performance, umbraco, umbraco7, yslow

YSlow is giving us a Grade F on our Umbraco controlled website for "Add Expires Headers"

If I set the `Expires:` into the far future, will a publish within Umbraco update these files? Or, because the cache means the site will not even request from the server, do I have to change the version numbers of the files to force a reload?

I'm looking to only cache images and stylesheets

Answer (score 4):

I typically configure this in IIS on the folders that contain the media and static files.

I believe it adds a web.config to the directory with the ClientCache configured properly.

More information here: [Client Cache  Documentation](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent/clientcache)